# Have Android 14 changed how display size bucket is calculated?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an emulator with a 1920x1200px display at 10.1 inches. In Android 13 this is identified as `xlarge` and all the resources under `xlarge` is loaded. If I change to Android 14 the display is now considered `large` and therefore the `large` resources are loaded instead.

I can't find any info on this change. Is this a bug or have this been documented somewhere?

**Edit:** The app still has api level 33 as target.

Answer (score 0):

Values for the smallest width qualifier are `dp`, because what matters is the amount of screen space available after the system accounts for **pixel density** (not the **raw pixel resolution**).

When I try with `Android Studio Iguana` for your values

[image]

It is set to **hdpi**.

However, when I set it with `Android Studio Giraffe`, it does not give the same result.

[image]

It is set to **220dpi**.

Documentation Note:

> The sizes you specify using resource qualifiers like smallest width
> are not the actual screen sizes. Rather, the sizes specify the width
> or height in dp units that are available to your app's window. The
> Android system might use some of the screen for system UI (such as the
> system bar at the bottom of the screen or the status bar at the top),
> so some of the screen might not be available for your layout.

And;

[image]